# Convert secured website to PDF

Tags: looking-for-a-script, mediawiki, pdf

I need to convert my MediaWiki site to PDF. The whole website, not just a page. Its a wiki with lots of articles.

Adobe Acrobat has function for this, but the problem is that the site is secured and requiers login. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: How many is "lots of articles"?

Comment: What is the wiki application behind the site?

Comment: You can use this library: http://html2pdf.fr

Comment: It looks like other users have this problem, because it doesn't work with logins within web pages. http://acrobatusers.com/forum/pdf-creation/web-capture-secure-pages-acrobat-9

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat lets say about 100.

Comment: @Su' same as wikipedia

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa No, i dont think so. 
"This library has been made to assist in the creation of PDF files, not to directly convert an HTML page." Besides too convert a html page is not enough, i need to convert the whole site, and also to be able to do it using username and password.

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood your problem. I thought you want to convert every page of the whole website like joomla does.

Answer (score 1):

This Wikimedia extension exports to PDF. http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Pdf_Export

It says

> If you invoke the Pdf Export special page directly, it lets you select a group of wiki pages and output them as a single pdf document.

There's also a warning on that page

> Warning: The author of this extension is no longer maintaining it,
>   meaning any reports for additional features and/or bugfixes will more
>   than likely be ignored. If you are interested in developing and
>   maintaining it, please contact the author.

I've not tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could mirror the site locally (and unsecured) then run the adobe acrobat function. Assuming you used a Wiki software just create a local install of the software without the password protection and connect it to the same database, then copy over any theme files you need.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used these myself, but there are some extensions that should be worth looking at:

- [Collection](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCollection) lets users(or presumably just you) create a collection of pages to export, which can be manually sorted.
- [PDF Export](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPdf_Export) allows individual pages to be exported as PDF. You might be able to combine this with a curl script, for example.
- [PDF Book](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPdf_Book) can export entire categories(if you use them) as single PDFs.

If you look around the extensions more, you might find something that will just do a completely automated dump of the entire site, but I'd personally lean toward Collection, in case you do want something out of the automatic order.